# canot establish connection to localhost through facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, localhost

i have created a new Facebook application and i used the following url as canvas url http://localhost/my_app/ 
my code works perfectly on localhost, but when i try to cal my application using the following url : apps.facebook.com/leenaaps its displays the following error:

> Unable to connect
>   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

what could be the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely do not have a local webserver running. If you do, it might be possible that Facebook uses `https://` but you did not configure/enable SSL.

Comment: Ihave configured the secure canvas url when i created my application, i used this https://localhost/my_app/

Comment: Then you need to configure your local webserver to support HTTPS.

Comment: thank you i could solve it by disabling the secure connection in Facebook

Answer (score 0):

localhost is resolved to ip 127.0.0.1 and this is the local loopback address whcih means it is not routable and cannot be accessed from the internet, So you cannot use it in your canvas url.

You have to use a valid and active domain name like domain.com. If you don't have a public web server you may use some DDNS service, google it some are free